# How do you unit test a servlet endpoint in apache camel?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tomcat, junit, apache-camel

I'm new to Camel and now have a simple route running in my Tomcat server. The route is built like this:

```
Processor generateWebResponse = new MySpecialProcessor();
from("servlet:///url?matchOnUriPrefix=true").process(generateWebResponse);
```

I tried a simple unit test like this:

```
Exchange lAuthRequest = createExchangeWithBody("[json body!]");
template.send("servlet:///url", lAuthRequest);
assertEquals("baseline body", lAuthRequest.getOut().getBody());
```

but get an exception indicating that I can't make a servlet endpoint. Here is the exception message:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: Endpoint[servlet:///url]. Reason: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You cannot create producer with servlet endpoint, please consider to use http or http4 endpoint.
```

This is new development so I don't have many constraints other than good design. I'm open to suggestions that require changes to the route. Also, if I'm doing something above that isn't idiomatic, I'm happy to revise the question with any suggested improvements.

Comment: You don't write a pure unit test, you have to write an integration test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a http client component to send a message to Tomcat, eg for example the camel--http component: http://camel.apache.org/http

You would then need to know the port number Tomcat runs the servlet at, eg

```
template.send("http://localhost:8080/myapp/myserver", lAuthRequest);
```

You would need to add camel-http to your classpath, eg if you use maven then add it as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks Claus! Is there a recommended way to separate out the servlet part of the route so that I can unit test the processor? Should I just do a plain old unit test against the processor?

Comment: I realize now that my question was unclear. I was trying to unit test routing logic inside of my webapp. I realized (as I've documented below) that most of my logic doesn't depend on the container. So Claus has answered a different part of my question which was how do I integration test a deployed webapp. The technique he describes it very powerful. I hope it sees more adoption.

Comment: Is there a way to print the full URL that the camel route can be triggered by?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by breaking the route into two parts. Now the route declaration looks like this:

```
from("servlet:///auth?matchOnUriPrefix=true").inOut("direct:auth");
from("direct:auth").process(new AuthorizationProcessor());
```

And the test looks like this:

```
Exchange lAuthRequest = createExchangeWithBody("test body");
template.send("direct:auth", lAuthRequest);
assertEquals("processed body", lAuthRequest.getOut().getBody());
```

This isn't a complete test, but allows me to get coverage of all of the route excluding the incoming servlet part. I think it's sufficient for the time being.